# ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor in VAE with concat

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am trying to extend the existing VAE network by leaking input to the variable for an autoregressive time series problem. For the same, I've used LSTM block and model works if I have standard network without `Concatenate` or `Add` layer. However, accuracy is not so great so I'd like to make it autoregressive in a sense that for synthesizing timeseries always take `mu` and `sigma` along with the previous samples as shown in the image.

[image: Vae]

Therefore, following code adds the input with an additional layer to match the dimension.

```
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers


class Sampling(layers.Layer):
    """Uses (z_mean, z_log_var) to sample z."""

    def call(self, inputs):
        z_mean, z_log_var = inputs
        batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
        dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
        epsilon = tf.keras.backend.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim),
                                  mean=0., stddev=1.)
        return z_mean + tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon    


# Build encoder and decoder
latent_dim = 2
input_shape = (4, 96)
encoder_input = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
enc = layers.LSTM(64)(encoder_input)
z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_mean")(enc)
z_log_sigma = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_log_var")(enc)
z = Sampling()([z_mean, z_log_sigma])
encoder = keras.Model(encoder_input, [z_mean, z_log_sigma, z], name="encoder")
encoder.summary()


# Extra layers for leaky input to decoder
leak_input_dec_ip = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
leak_input_dec = layers.LSTM(2)(leak_input_dec_ip)

# Decoder where we have inputs from leaky input and sampling layer
inp_z = keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
dec = layers.Concatenate()([leak_input_dec, inp_z]) # or Add
dec = layers.RepeatVector(96)(inp_z)
dec = layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)(dec)
out = layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(96))(dec)
decoder = keras.Model([leak_input_dec, inp_z], out) 
decoder.summary()
```

But, it keeps giving the error `ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_39:0", shape=(None, 4, 96), dtype=float32) at layer "lstm_29". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: ['repeat_vector_11', 'lstm_30', 'time_distributed_8']`

Comment: In the decoder, should it be `leak_input_dec` or `leak_input_dec_ip`?

Comment: That's so silly of me! Thanks for pointing it our @M.Innat :)